# setState() causes state variable to be undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am, for the most part, following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-modern-web-application-to-manage-customer-information-with-django-and-react-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial.

My Django API's set up well. I have this service function:

```
export default class GoalService{
    getGoals() {
        const url = `${API_URL}/api/goals`;
        return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data);
    } 
}
```

Which is called by the `componentDidMount` method in my `GoalList`:

```
class GoalTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            goals: [],
            now: now.getDate(),
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var  self  =  this;
        goalService.getGoals().then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            self.setState({ goals: result.data })
        });
    }

    render() { ... }
```

(This is **step 8** of the above-linked tutorial).

Now, when I try to use `{ this.state.goals.map(...) }`, I get the error `TypeError: this.state.goals is undefined`. Looking at other threads, a lot of people seem to have had this problem—but it comes about because they've used `setState()` *outside* of the request being made and, since `setState()` is asynchronous, the state is set to something blank. I'm using it inside of a call to `then`, so I don't think that's the issue.

I tried adding a second argument to `then` (in case this operation wasn't successful), but, the `getGoals()` call **is** successful, and successfully prints out the JSON sent back by Django's API. Similarly, I can see that the request went as expected in the Network tab of the developer tools.

What could be going wrong here? Why isn't the state properly updating w/ the returned JSON?

Comment: You're positive `result.data` isn't `undefined`? All you've done above is log `result` itself, i can't be sure that result is an object or if it's json, or if it even has a data property.

Comment: If `this.state.goals` is becoming `undefined` after you've already initialized it in the constructor, then you must be setting it to that. In other words - it looks like `result.data` is undefined. I notice that you're doing `.data` in both your service and your component - are you accidentally effectively doing `response.data.data`?

Comment: @KevinB That's the problem. :l The tutorial's got a typo in it—I am, as @JoeClay said, effectively doing `response.data.data`.

Comment: @JoeClay and I can't comment on this tutorial, because it's behind a paywall. Ah, well. Hopefully this question will lead others in the right direction. Thanks very much you two

Comment: No problem - nothing worse than when your code breaks due to dodgy documentation, always a pain to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Ah, in fact, I still have a DigitalOcean account from when my website used to be hosted there - I will comment on your behalf :)

Comment: @JoeClay Oh, awesome. Thanks much. :D I'll gladly accept your answer if you put one down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the tutorial has a typo, which means that the code tries to access `response.data.data` instead of `response.data`.

The fix would be to remove this extra level of drilling down into the object:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    goalService.getGoals().then(function (result) {
        self.setState({ goals: result }) // no .data
    });
}
```

Also, note that you could make this code simpler by using arrow functions (which automatically bind the `this` from the place that they're defined) and the object initialization shorthand:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    // { goals } is the same as { goals: goals }
    goalService.getGoals().then(goals => this.setState({ goals }));
}
```